# Creating nested dictionary dynamically in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a nested dictionary dynamically using python.

for example I need to create a function that will take the nodes and construct a nested dictionary with these nodes.

For example:

inputs:
'customers.applicant.individual.first_name'

output:

```
customers : {
      applicant: {
                 individual:{
                              firstname: {}

             }
           }
         }
```

and for each node, i need to make sure if it exist already if it does than skip else create the node. Can anyone please provide any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that python dictionaries are mutable and do something like the following:

```
input_item1 = 'customers.applicant.individual.first_name.Bob'
input_item2 = 'customers.applicant.individual.first_name.Jim'

inputs = [input_item1, input_item2]
output_dictionary = dict()


for input_item in inputs:
    current_dict = output_dictionary
    for item in input_item.split('.'):   
        if item in current_dict:
            current_dict = current_dict[item]
        else:
            current_dict[item] = dict()
            current_dict = current_dict[item]

print(output_dictionary)
```

Basically, because dictionaries are mutable, if you modify 'current_dict', the entry in the larger dictionary that you are referencing gets updated too.

This gives an output of:

```
{'customers': {'applicant': {'individual': {'first_name': {'Bob': {}, 'Jim': {}}}}}}
```